# Write a function to divide a number by 3 without using /, % and * operators. itoa() available?

Tags: algorithm, math

I tried to solve it myself but I could not get any clue.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: If You are allowing + and - there is no sense of preventing /, * and % of using. one can drive function. Or + and - should also be banned.. :)

Answer (score 14):

Are you *supposed* to use itoa() for this assignment? Because then you could use that to convert to a base 3 string, drop the last character, and then restore back to base 10.

Answer (score 11):

Using the mathematical relation:

```
1/3 == Sum[1/2^(2n), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

We have

```
int div3 (int x) {
   int64_t blown_up_x = x;
   for (int power = 1; power < 32; power += 2)
      blown_up_x += ((int64_t)x) << power;
   return (int)(blown_up_x >> 33);
}
```

If you can only use 32-bit integers,

```
int div3 (int x) {
     int two_third = 0, four_third = 0;
     for (int power = 0; power < 31; power += 2) {
        four_third += x >> power;
        two_third += x >> (power + 1);
     }
     return (four_third - two_third) >> 2;
}
```

The `4/3 - 2/3` treatment is used because `x >> 1` is `floor(x/2)` instead of `round(x/2)`.

Comment: The "64-bit" version *does* work. The "32-bit" version will at most be off by 1 or -1.

Comment: this is just binary representation of 1/3

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT: Oops, I misread the title's question. Multiply operator is forbidden as well.**

**Anyway, I believe it's good not to delete this answer for those who didn't know about dividing by non power of two constants.**

---

The solution is to multiply by a magic number and then to extract the 32 leftmost bits:

divide by 3 is equivalent to multiply by 1431655766 and then to shift by 32, in C:

```
int divideBy3(int n)
{
  return (n * 1431655766) >> 32;
}
```

See [Hacker's Delight Magic number calculator](http://hackersdelight.org/magic.htm).

Comment: Read the title: "without using `/`, `%` and `*`".

Comment: @Gaim: yes I just misread the title. I was editing my answer while you were writing your comment

Comment: I pity the fool that has to pick that up for maintenance... :)

Comment: @Paolo: with commented code, it might not be a problem. It's good to have it in your optimization bag of tricks, and well parts of the code that are not really performance critical must not use it obviously

Comment: I like this answer. The multiplication can be rewritten as a for(int i = 0; i < 1431655766) n += n;
Than the answer is in line with the requirements.

Comment: @Fortega: `x += n;`. `n += n` will result in `n * 2^1431655766` :)

Comment: @Fortega, there ought be be a nice way to use `>>` and `+` to quickly multiply by big numbers. For example, `5*x == (x<<2) + x`.  A long expression, with many `<<`, should be able to do `*1431655766`

Comment: I upvoted this because I noticed multiplication by 1431655766 in compiler output, did a Google search for the number, and learned thanks to this answer that what was going on was division by 3. (Sorry.)

Answer (score 9):

x/3 = e^(ln(x) - ln(3))

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution implemented in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int letUserEnterANumber()
{
    int numberEnteredByUser;
    std::cin >> numberEnteredByUser;
    return numberEnteredByUser;
}

int divideByThree(int x)
{
    std::cout << "What is " << x << " divided by 3?" << std::endl;
    int answer = 0;
    while ( answer + answer + answer != x )
    {
        answer = letUserEnterANumber();
    }
}
```

;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
if(number<0){ // Edited after comments
number = -(number);
}
quotient = 0;
while (number-3 >= 0){ //Edited after comments..
number = number-3;
quotient++;
}//after loop exits value in number will give you reminder
```

EDIT: Tested and working perfectly fine :(

Hope this helped. :-)

Comment: Does not handle negative numbers

Comment: It will be better if while condition will be `number >= 3` because you can get this: `5:3=2`

Comment: Does still not work. It will return one too much.
Try number=3, you will notice how it will return quotient=2 instead of quotient = 1

Comment: @kigurai : it wouldnt return quotient = 2 for number=3.. check again :( ..else my eyes and my brain should be tricking me.. i even tested the same.. please check the code thoroughly before putting comments and down voting.. pls

Comment: @Fortega 5/3 is 1.66666..i agree...here 1 is quotient.. if you check my code it gives you quotient as 1 and reminder as 2.. 2/3 is 0.66666...so both together will give you 1.6666..

Answer (score 2):

```
long divByThree(int x)
{    
  char buf[100];
  itoa(x, buf, 3); 
  buf[ strlen(buf) - 1] = 0; 
  char* tmp; 
  long res = strtol(buf, &tmp, 3);

  return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like homework :)

I image you can write a function which iteratively divides a number. E.g. you can model what you do with a pen and a piece of paper to divide numbers. Or you can use shift operators and + to figure out if your intermediate results is too small/big and iteratively apply corrections. I'm not going to write down the code though ...

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy, so easy I'm only going to hint at the answer --

Basic boolean logic gates (and,or,not,xor,...) don't do division.  Despite this handicap CPUs can do division.  Your solution is obvious: find a reference which tells you how to build a divisor with boolean logic and write some code to implement that.

Comment: I should have added, that if you want you could implement a circuit that only divides by 3, but why not implement a circuit for general division.

Comment: well divide by a constant is going to use less gates - often an important optimization in hardware design (guess it depends on what class this is for)

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int  div3(unsigned int m) {
   unsigned long long n = m;
   n += n << 2;
   n += n << 4;
   n += n << 8;
   n += n << 16;
   return (n+m) >> 32;
}
```

Comment: This works, and looks so simple ... but what was your logic?

Answer (score 1):

```
int divideby3(int n)
{
    int x=0;
    if(n<3) { return 0; }
    while(n>=3)
    {
        n=n-3;
        x++;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a property from the numbers: A number is divisible by 3 if its sum is divisible by3.
Take the individual digits from itoa() and then use switch function for them recursively with additions and itoa()

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

for positive integer division

```
result = 0
while (result + result + result < input)
 result +=1
return result
```

Comment: Only integer division. Does not handle negative numbers. If input is is large a lot of unneccesary additions are made.

Comment: yep but it does actually work with those constraints in contrast to another similar answer

Comment: Yes, it is much better in that regard :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this, in some kind of Python like pseudo-code. It divides the answer into an integer part and a fraction part. If you want to convert it to a floating point representation then I am not sure of the best way to do that.

```
 x = <a number>  
 total = x
 intpart = 0
 fracpart = 0

 % Find the integer part
 while total >= 3
    total = total - 3
    intpart = intpart + 1

 % Fraction is what remains
 fracpart = total


 print "%d / 3 = %d + %d/3" % (x, intpart, fracpart)
```

Note that this will not work for negative numbers. To fix that you need to modify the algorithm:

```
  total = abs(x)
  is_neg = abs(x) != x

  ....

  if is_neg
      print "%d / 3 = -(%d + %d/3)" % (x, intpart, fracpart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert 1/3 into binary

so 1/3=0.01010101010101010101010101

and then just "multiply" whit this number using shifts and sum

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution posted on http://bbs.chinaunix.net/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=3776384&page=1&extra=#pid22323016

```
int DividedBy3(int A) {
    int p = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= 32; i += 2)
        p += A << i;
    return (-p);
}
```

Please say something about that, thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `O(log(n))` way to do it with no bit shifting, so it can handle numbers up-to and including your biggest register size.

(c-style code)

```c
long long unsigned Div3 (long long unsigned n)
{
    // base case:
    if (n < 6)
        return (n >= 3);

    long long unsigned division = 0;
    long long unsigned remainder = 0;

    // Used for results for only a single power of 2
    // Initialise for 2^0
    long long unsigned tmp_div = 0;
    long long unsigned tmp_rem = 1;

    for (long long unsigned pow_2 = 1; pow_2 && (pow_2 <= n); pow_2 += pow_2)
    {
        if (n & pow_2)
        {
            division += tmp_div;
            remainder += tmp_rem;
        }
        
        if (tmp_rem == 1)
        {
            tmp_div += tmp_div;
            tmp_rem = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp_div += tmp_div + 1;
            tmp_rem = 1;
        }
    }
    
    return division + Div3(remainder);
}
```

It uses recursion, but note that the number drops exponentially in size at each iteration, so the time complexity (TC) is really:
`O(TC) = O(log(n) + log(log(n)) + log(log(log(n))) + ... + z)`
where `z < 6`.

---

### Proof that it's O(log(n)):

We note that the number at each recursion strictly decreases (by at least 1):

So `series = [log(log(n))] + [log(log(log(n)))] + [...] + [z])` has at most `log(log(n))` sums.

implies:

`series <= log(log(n))*log(log(n))`

implies:

`O(TC) = O(log(n) + log(log(n))*log(log(n)))`

Now we note for `n` sufficiently large:
`sqrt(x) > log(x)`

iff:

`x/sqrt(x) > log(x)`

implies:

`x/log(x) > log(x)`

iff:

`x > log(x)*log(x)`

So `O(x) > O(log(x)*log(x))`

Now let `x = log(n)`

implies:

`O(log(n)) > O(log(log(n))*log(log(n)))`

and given:
`O(TC) = O(log(n) + log(log(n))*log(log(n)))`

implies:

`O(TC) = O(log(n))`

Answer (score -2):

Slow and naive, but it should work, if an exact divisor exists. Addition is allowed, right?

```
for number from 1 to input
  if number == input+input+input
    return number
```

Extending it for fractional divisors is left as an exercise to the reader.
Basically test for +1 and +2 I think...

Comment: no, this always returns input (mult instead of divide and wrong loop range) and assumes input > 0

Comment: Uhm, this doesn't do division at all and will never return anything.
"number" can be at most "input", so "number == input + input + input" will never be true.

Comment: you should replace the 'number == input+input+input' by 'input == number+number+number'